# Do i need a new collar on a toilet if i have a vinyl floor? never had one before

Tags: toilet

Do i need a new collar on a toilet if i have a vinyl floor? never had one before

this is my second toilet and it was leaking.  even before the plumber started the work, the price went form $220.00 to $440.00 because he said I might need a new collar.

I never had a problem with the last 2 plumbers not needing one and when 2 new toilets were put in it was not needed.

this plumber said they require it without even looking at the toilet.  I am a single 68 year old female and i feel like I am being taken advantage of.  is it a must or can the ring be 1/4" below the floor like everyone states?

Comment: If by collar you mean toilet flange, get another plumber! I have seen them over 80 years old on cast and 30 or more on plastic. With this said you don't know if one is needed until the toilet has been pulled. If it is required a top of the line replacement that drops into cast or plastic pipe 50$ with an hour to cut the cast worse case. Sounds like this guy is just trying to scam you call some one else.

Answer (score 1):

The ring can be 1/4" below the floor, although level with the floor is best. Modern wax rings (and some other newfangled sealing rings) are able to accomodate this.

There may be some other reason the plumber is recommending repair or replacement of the *closet ring*. Armed with this knowledge, ask him/her to explain in detail why this is necessary. If you are unsatisfied with the response, thank the plumber and say you will call them back after you think about it. Then call some other reputable, licensed, insured plumber and get a second opinion.

Comment: P.S.- I am curious as to why you are now on your third toilet in that location. A toilet should last 40 years, if not longer.